# AJAX function is not firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello everyone I want to parse array to Codeigniter controller but my code is not working can you please tell me where is a mistake in this code. I am a new in jQuery I know it is a very basic mistake.

jQuery Code:

```
$("#add_state").click(function(){
      var addstate = {
        State: $.trim($('#statename').val()
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/geo/add_state",
        data: addstate,
        success: function(response){
          alert(response);
        }
      });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<form role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">State Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="State" class="form-control" id="statename" placeholder="Enter State Name">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="add_state">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When you view source of the page, is the `url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/geo/add_state"` still exactly that?

Comment: Try to change type of button to button not submit 
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="add_state">Submit</button>`

Comment: You haven't passed event into your function so the prevent defulat is probably not working: `$("#add_state").click(function(event)`

Comment: @JonStirling yes `url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/geo/add_state"`is working controller

Comment: A parenthesis is missing at this line `State: $.trim($('#statename').val()`

Comment: You did not define `event`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trim is not closed properly

it suppose to be like this

```
$("#add_state").click(function(){
      var addstate = {
        State: $.trim($('#statename').val())
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/geo/add_state",
        data: addstate,
        success: function(response){
          alert(response);
        }
      });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I am a laughing on my self so basic error. Next time I will take care of symbols.

Comment: @RushabhShah, next time, look at your JavaScript console and check for errors.  Basic troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Missing `)` in `State: $.trim($('#statename').val()`. Change it to `State: $.trim($('#statename').val())`.
2. Use `$(document).on('click', '#add_state', function() {` instead`$("#add_state").click(function(){`. Because first solution will work, if you add script before dom element was created.
3. Check url, maybe it's incorrect.